# mySQL gather data between hours of the day passing through midnight with date increment

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, range, auto-increment

I am trying to get data from a database between 8PM (say, today) and 2AM tomorrow.

I have been using clauses such as `where hour(date_field)>=20 and hour(date_field) <23` to obtain data in the same day.

Here the date_field is `datetime`

All I want is to be able to tell SQL to get data after 8PM today, increment the datefield and then get data till 2AM tomorrow.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is the datatype of the field, date, datetime, or timestamp?  If date your out of luck as time isn't stored.

Answer (score 1):

The normal pattern for retrieving rows based on a datetime range is perform comparisons on the bare column, comparing the column value to constants derived from expressions.

To get rows for a single contiguous range, 8PM today to 2AM tomorrow, for example:

```
  WHERE t.date_column >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 20 HOUR
    AND t.date_column  < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 26 HOUR
```

To unpack that a little bit: NOW() returns current datetime, the DATE() function truncates the time portion to midnight, then we add back in enough hours to get '8PM today', or enough hours to get '2AM tomorrow'.

---

If you are meaning to retrieve multiple "8PM to 2AM" periods, for a whole series of days.

First, you'd want an upper and lower bound of the `date_column` to be retrieved (unless you want every possible date)

```
 WHERE t.date_column >= '2014-08-01 20:00:00'
   AND t.date_column  < '2014-10-02 02:00:00'
```

From that, we need to filter out all of the rows that aren't between 8PM and 2AM.  One convenient way to do that would be to "subtract" two hours from the datetime col, and check for hour >= 6PM.

```
   AND HOUR(t.date_column + INTERVAL -2 HOUR) >= 18
```

Note that the expression involving `date_column` will need to be evaluated for EVERY row in the table, unless there are some other predicates that filter rows out. With a suitable index available, MySQL can use an index range scan operation for predicates of the form `date_column >= const` and `date_column < const`. (It can't do that when the column is wrapped in a function or expression.)

Comment: DATE(NOW()) can be repalced with CURRENT_DATE